# How to view old battle reports in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

After a night of gaming I wanted to check the battle report of one of my rounds in Battlefield 3. I am probably missing something or Battlelog is just borked as usual, but how do I view old battle reports? I can only see the last five maps and didn't find any way to see the older reports. (It was the sixth report I was interested in :p)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to your profile (not your stats pages, but your user profile), the second "section" down will show your last 16 battle reports, I haven't been able to find a way to see older reports.

Your profile is `http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/user/<soldier_name>/`

[image]

Comment: If you check your profile on bf3stats.com (bf3stats.com/stats_<platform>/<gamertag>) and routinely check it after each time playing, it will save past battle reports (so you can access ones long deleted from battlelog's report engine)

Answer (score 3):

It shows only the last five. Tough luck.

Buut, there is a brute force method, in which you can try the url manually:

A typical Battle Report URL looks like the following:

http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/show/3653566/1/352560313/

The number before the last slash might be different for you, but it is the same across all games.

The one after /show/ is the incrementing number for the report. 
Past reports mean a smaller number, so you can count back and call the URL repeatedly until you see the one you are looking for.

Provided, the report has not already been deleted from the report engine.